# Saving property with java keyword as name with Realm

Tags: android, realm

We currently save the next class in Realm:

```
open class Location(
  var lat: Double? = 0.0,
  var long: Double? = 0.0
) : RealmObject()
```

The strange behaviour I see that after saving negative longitude we retrieve it from Realm as 0.0.

Any clue, thoughts or it is impossible?

Comment: We would probably need to see your read/write code. I just created that object and saved it with a value if -3.141 for both properties and it wrote and read correctly

Comment: @Jay check https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7492

Comment: BTW @Jay, are you on the Kotlin side and Android? What version of Realm did you use for the testing?

Comment: Sorry, I was just checking if you tried to reproduce it on the Android and Kotlin side. Yeah, I'm lucky this week with magic bug fixing.

Comment: That is so weird. We are not duplicating the issue at the moment. We are not Android, our platform is Swift, but are rolling through different platforms trying to duplicate the issue. We initially had the var as `longitude` which worked and thought if we changed it to `long` it would fail but it's currently working. Try creating that class in Realm Studio and see what happens.

Comment: Let's wait for the Realm people triage. I might be wrong in the conclusions.

Comment: Oke, Realm confirmed that it is already a known issue

Comment: Very interesting and super good info. So it appears it's not a Realm issue but a Java keyword issue. `long` is a reserved word in [Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_ref_keywords.asp). The issue appears to be what to do about it as it should be flagged with an error thrown and corrective action suggested.

Comment: It is definitely a realm issue :) They also agree about it.

Comment: From Realm: *Realm itself does not have any reserved keywords for properties, but language restrictions might prohibit defining some model classes. `default` is a reserved keyword in Java, and the Realm annotation processor runs on Java...* and that is followed by *Since this a language restriction there isn't much Realm can do about it* Also note they changed the title of your issue to **Using Java reserved keywords in Kotlin model**. Hopefully they will address it since it's been open for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging it turns out the Realm issue - `long` is probably a keyword for schema or so. Please follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7492 if you're interested.